# Ansible SSH hangs for no clear reason

Tags: linux, networking, ssh

I am trying to get Ansible 2.7 setup for an initial enviroment of six Linux servers that run Ubuntu 18.04. It seems I have the most basic of problems, but cant get it figured out.

I am simply trying to do an Ansible ping to each server to make sure I have good connectivity from my Ansible control machine to the servers. I actually know I can ping/SSH to each server from the control box, but I want my team to start proofing environments like this with an Ansible ping, not a simple network ping.

I have edited `ansible.cfg` to disable ssh host key checking.

When I run the the command line ping, it hangs at this:

```
$ ansible all -i 10.219.85.38, -m ping -u MY-ID -k -vvv
ansible 2.7.9
  config file = /home/MY-ID/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/MY-ID/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15) [GCC 7.3.0]
Using /home/MY-ID/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
SSH password:
Parsed 10.219.85.38, inventory source with host_list plugin
META: ran handlers
<10.219.85.38> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: MY-ID
<10.219.85.38> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d9 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o User=MY-ID -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/MY-ID/.ansible/cp/1cfc2e51ea 10.219.85.38 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~MY-ID && sleep 0'"'"''
```

Comment: The [user1657986](https://superuser.com/users/1657986/user1657986) on 2022 Jan 11, stated _"It looks like the password chat is different than expected. See `sshpass -P`"_.

Comment: The user [bladedoyle](https://superuser.com/users/553794/bladedoyle) on 2021, Jun 9 stated _"Issues on the target host or not, ansible should not hang on ssh."_

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue on the target host.  There is an MFA autentication system involved here and that is likely the issue.

I am looking at `tail -f /var/log/auth.log` and see the issue there.

Comment: If this path lead to the problem resolution, see if you can find the time to complete the answer and accept it for the other users... Someone is still answering in the attempt to solve your problem after so long... `:-)`